# SAP HANA: Is there a way to define schema and table name as input parameters of a procedure?

Tags: sql, procedure, hana

I am creating a procedure to delete table rows duplicates.

Code works fine, i want to transform code into a procedure. I can not find a way to set [**Schema]** and **[Table]** as input parameters.

```
Create procedure DUPL_DELETE (in inp1 nvarchar(100), in inp2 nvarchar(200))
as 
begin

-- Select the distinct rows into a New temporary Table
create local temporary table #Mytemp
LIKE "SCHEMA"."TABLE";
-- LIKE :inp2.:inp1        Desired code to be(does not work)
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM "SCHEMA"."TABLE"
INTO "SCHEMA".#Mytemp;

-- Delete the rows from table
DELETE FROM "SCHEMA"."TABLE";

-- Insert disctinct data back in to the Table and drop the temporary table
INSERT INTO "SCHEMA"."TABLE" SELECT * FROM "SCHEMA".#Mytemp;
DROP TABLE "SCHEMA".#Mytemp;

end;
```

Help guys please

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL for this.

Comment: Thank you, but i think it's not recommanded by SAP HANA, I have already done a test based on your suggestion, it works, but there's a message like not recommanded to use dynamic SQL for such queries

Comment: This message is a *warning* message - which means your code still compiles and executes. It's designed to draw attention to what is very likely not a great choice for development in SQL/SQLScript. Trying to be "flexible" about tables, views and schemas is trying to circumvent the fact that SQL is *statically* typed (and tables are the main data types). With this "flexibility" all sorts of problems can arise, both in execution performance as well in maintainability. In many cases it is a lot easier/better to handle the "flexibility" in the application layer or the schema generation process.

Comment: @LarsBr. It goes from warning to error if you try to use it in a procedure that returns the results as a VIEW ( READS SQL DATA WITH RESULT VIEW VIEWNAMEXX AS BEGIN....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing the schema using following sample command:

```
set schema OTHERSCHEMA;
```

But for table name, you need to build and [run dynamic SQL statement](http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/execute-sql-dynamically-from-hana-database-table.aspx) using

```
execute immediate :sql;
```

Comment: About "set schema OTHERSCHEMA;" SAP HANA also considers this dynamic SQL...ran into this same problem with a stored procedure with result view that forces the SQLs to be static, nothing dynamic....

Comment: Without your code & the error message this comment doesn’t add to the discussion. How about opening a separate question instead?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE OriginalSchema.procDynamicSchema( 
     IN schemaId NVARCHAR(250)
     )
     LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT 
     SQL SECURITY INVOKER 
     READS SQL DATA AS

BEGIN
/***************************** 
  Write your procedure logic 
*****************************/
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
 'SELECT  
    "Id",
    "UUID",
    "IdpId",
    "Email",
    "firstName",
    "lastname"
FROM ' || :schemaId || '."Users"' ;  
END;
```

then call it :

```
CALL "OriginalSchema"."procDynamicSchema"(SCHEMAID => 'XYZ')
```

p.s: I don't think you can dynamically pass the OriginalSchema name, because to create a procedure you must at least have a schema where you're actually trying to create your procedure at fist place